# Complex solutions of polynomial question

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

$2z^3-6z^2+mz+n = 0$ $m, n$ are real and $1+\sqrt{ 2} i$ is a solution. Find $m$ and $n$.

**Attempt to solve :**

Giving the known theorem $1-\sqrt{2}i$ is also a solution, so we can substitute each time one of the roots and get a system in two unknowns to solve. I find this to be rather complex and not elegant. I wonder, are there any other solutions to this problem, which are perhaps not as tedious?

Comment: Use Vieta's formulas.

Comment: how to you suggest to do that?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

By Vieta's formulas, the sum of the roots is $ -\frac {6}{2} = 3 $. You know that two of the roots are $ 1 + 2i $ and $ 1- 2i $, so the third root must be $ 1 $. Plugging in $1$ to the polynomial we obtain that $ m + n = 4 $. By Vieta's formulas we also know that the product of the roots is $ -\frac {n}{2} = (1+2i)(1-2i)(1) = 5 $. Therefore, $ n = -10 $ and $ m = 14 $.

Comment: elegant, although we were never taught this...is there something more?

Comment: Yeah, typically Vieta's formulas aren't taught in high school classes. I learned them from problem solving practice for competition math.

Comment: If you want to learn more about Vieta's formulas go here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta's_formulas

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $(z-a)(z-b)(z-c)$ has roots $a,b,c$ and if $z_0$ is a complex root, then its conjugate too :).

Comment: I think I mentioned it already...

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** You know that $1+\sqrt{2}i$ and $1+\sqrt{2}i$ are solutions of
$$z^3-3z^2+\frac{m}{2}z+\frac{n}{2} = 0$$
-3, the coefficient of $z^2$ is the sum of the solutions, so you easily get the third.